# Incrementing while loop isn't working in some test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, while-loop, calculation

I have to define a function where:

> Starting with a positive integer `original`, keep multiplying `original`
>   by `n` and calculate the sum of all multiples generated including
>   `original` until the sum is no longer smaller than `total`. Return the
>   minimum number of multiplications needed to reach at value at or above
>   the given total.

So for example:

1. `multiply_until_total_reached (1,5,2)`

   1*2=2, (1+2)<5, 2*2=4, (1+2+4)>5, 2 multiplications needed
2. `multiply_until_total_reached (1,15,2)`

   1*2=2, (1+2)<15, 2*2=4, (1+2+4)<15, 4*2=8, (1+2+4+8)=15, 3 multiplications

My current code works but the returned value is off by 1 in some cases. In a 1,1038,2 case, I get 9 multiplication needed instead of 10 but in the 1,15,2 case, I get the correct amount (3) multiplications.

Here's my code:

```
def multiply_until_total_reached(original, total, n):
    if total < original:
        return 0
    elif total > original:
        sumofdigits = 0 #declares var to keep track of sum of digits to compare to total
        timesofmult = 0 #track how many multiplication operations
        while sumofdigits <= total + 1:
            multnum = original * n
            sumofdigits = multnum + original
            original = multnum
            sumofdigits = sumofdigits + multnum
            timesofmult = timesofmult + 1
        return timesofmult
```

What's causing it to be off?

Comment: You are missing a `total == original` case. You should probably have `if total <= original: return 0`.

Comment: I strongly feel there's probably an O(1) or O(logn) solution for this as well if you want it..

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj this *is* the `O(log n)` solution where `n` represents the value of `total`.

Comment: @EvilTak Ohh.. I meant O(logn n) where n is number of multiplications needed :-P.. It might be overkill in this case though.. Notice how it's corelated with the sum of a GP..

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj I know, this can be done in O(1) time using the GP formula and logarithmic inequalities, although that will be slightly more complex if `n` lies between 0 and 1 and will not work at all if `n` is negative. This solution is guaranteed to be correct for all `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, lot smaller and neater. Explanation is in the comments..

```
def multiply_until_total_reached(original, total, n):
        sum = original    #Initialize sum to original
        mult_no = 0

        while sum < total:       #Will auto return 0 if original>=total
            sum += original*n    #Add original * n
            original = original*n   #Update the new original
            mult_no += 1    #Increase multiplications by 1

        return mult_no

print multiply_until_total_reached(1,5,2)
print multiply_until_total_reached(1,15,2)
print multiply_until_total_reached(1,1038,2)

#Output
#2
#3
#10
```

Comment: While this solves the problem in a more concise way, it does not really answer the question, and does not help the OP to understand.

Comment: Yeah, If he was a student and wanted to learn and find out his mistakes this wouldn't be of much help.. but if he was working and wanted some neater code and a quick answer this would help him a lot imo..

Comment: Honestly, I was reading this code and it makes perfect sense to me. It's just a different (and faster/cleaner) approach to the problem. I understood my error as Evil Tak explained it below.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are reassigning `sumofdigits` in every loop iteration. You just have to add `multnum` to `sumofdigits` in every iteration (`sumofdigits += multnum`). Also, your loop condition needs to be fixed to `sumofdigits < total` since you have to "Return the minimum number of multiplications needed to reach *at* value **or** *above* the given total."

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. So I must delete the first sumofdigits = multnum + original and just use the sumofdigits += multnum? TIA

Comment: @Pritster5 yes.

Answer (score 1):

Since solution for your code has already been posted, and you accept alternative solutions, allow me to suggest the following, which makes good use of Python's > 3.2 `accumulate()` function:

```
from itertools import accumulate, count

def multiply_until_total_reached(original, total, n):
    for i, result in enumerate(accumulate(original*n**c for c in count())):
        if result >= total: return i

assert multiply_until_total_reached(1,5,2) == 2
assert multiply_until_total_reached(1,15,2) == 3
assert multiply_until_total_reached(1,1038,2) == 10
```

Comment: I appreciate the solution but unfortunately I was not allowed to use such functions in the code.